# API fetch no me funciona en gadget de Bloger

Tags: html, css

He querido incluir, en un gadget de Bloger, un calendario que me funciona muy bien en mi sitio, pero en el blog no me enlaza con el archivo que contiene los archivos diarios invocados con "fetch". He probado a poner la url completa y sigue sin funcionar. Con esta síntaxis me funciona en mi sitio: fetch("/santoral/" + file).
Adjunto todo el script.
Vete link: https://amadoresdecristo.org/CB.html

```js
<script>
  function GetSantoralHoyFile(){
  const f = new Date();
  const d = String(f.getDate()).padStart(2, '0'); 
  const m = String(f.getMonth()+1).padStart(2, '0');   
  return `${d}-${m}-${f.getFullYear()}.txt`;
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {  
 const file = GetSantoralHoyFile();
 fetch("/santoral/" + file)
  .then(resp=>resp.text())
  .then(resp=>{
      const cont = document.getElementById("santoral_contenido");
      cont.innerHTML = resp;
   });
});</script>
```

Comment: Tienes problema de CORS. (El navegador no deja consultar un sitio que sea distinto). En el servidor de tu sitio NO Blog debes configurar las cabecera de respuesta par que lo permita.  O duplicar los archivos TXT y colocarlos en el blog

Comment: Buenas tardes, Yussef. Ese código me lo hiciste el otro día, y te lo agradezco infinito, pues funciona de maravilla en el sitio.
Creo que no sé cómo hacer lo que me propones, "configurar las cabecera de respuesta par". Y la duplicación de archivos TXT no sé dónde he de ponerlos en el blog, pues si hago entradas (serían 365) estarían a la vista de todos.

Comment: Adicionalmente te recomiendo poner más ganas en las preguntas. Una buena pregunta debe tener toda la información necesaria para responderla en la publicación (sin recurrir a link externos, aunque los puedes colocar como anexo). Es esperable (por muchos usuarios revisores) que además señales lo que has intentado hacer hasta el momento para solucionar tu propio problema. Saludos

Comment: El "como" configurar la cabecera depende del servidor que estes usando (y de las posibilidades de configuración que te brinde el hosting contratado). Me parece que esto sobrepasa tus conocimientos, por lo que si quieres solucionar el tema rápido debes subir los TXT al blog (seguramente será el mismo método que se hace para subir imagenes)

Comment: Ya he puesto que probé a poner la url completa: fetch("https://www.amadoresdecristo.org/santoral/" + file) y que no funcionaba. No he podido hacer otra cosa que pueda incluir en mi pregunta.

Comment: Ahora que lo pienso la otra alternativa es que uses un `iframe`

Comment: Por desgracia, a mis 78 años, y con muchos sin practicar, tengo que reconocer que me pierdo las más de las veces, por lo que te agradecería si me pudieras indicar el código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal como señala en los comentarios, tienes un problema de `CORS`, por lo que el navegador te impide realizar una consulta `fetch` a otro dominio.

La forma más sencilla de lograr algo parecido a lo que buscas, es usar un `iframe`, para ello en la creación de `Gadget` de Blogger agregas uno nuevo del tipo `HTML / JavaScript` y dentro de contenido pones el siguiente código

```
<iframe src="https://amadoresdecristo.org/CB.html" style="border:0; height:434px;overflow:hidden;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" "></iframe>
```

El problema de este método es que no tienes forma fácil de hacer el alto (height) dinámico y autoajustable, por lo que deberás encontrar una altura a pelo, que se ajuste bien a los 365 días (yo he puesto 434px al azar)

Comment: Eres un máquina Yussef. Infinitas gracias por tu amabilidad y profesionalidad. Tienes en este pobre viejo todo mi reconocimiento. A tu disposición. Funciona perfectamente.

Comment: http://blog.amadoresdecristo.org/

Comment: @MancipioLimusTurpe Un gusto haber podido ayudarlo, aunque sea un poco

Comment: La ayuda ha sido muy importante para este pobre viejo. Gracias a que sois una juventud muy valiosa. No sé cómo agradecerte el gran favor que me has hecho.

Comment: Gracias por soportar mis fallos.